# z-index is not working properly in IE7

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, z-index

**Here is the scenario:**

[image]

I was trying to put search `div` (black color) on top of `nav` (slate blue color) using `z-index` for **IE7** but its not working.

**Here goes the dummy Markup:**

```
<div id="header">
  <div class="container">
    <div id="search"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <div id="nav"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

On **CSS** rule, `#header` is positioned as `relative` where `#search` & `#nav` are positioned as `absolute`. Any idea, how can I put the `#search` on top of `#nav`?

NOTE: for some reason, I need to put them in two different `div`. My **CSS** worked properly with **IE8**.

Comment: Did you try to set position and z-index to `.container`s? If so, please JSFiddle.

Comment: [CanIUse on z-index](http://caniuse.com/#search=z-index) - IE8 struggled with compatibility so you might struggle with IE7.

Comment: @panther, i tried that already, didn't worked!

Comment: @BeatAlex, I hate IE, perhaps we all do that -_-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to **@Pete** as his answer gave me a clue to solve this! :) I'd like to share it:

For the second `.container`, I've set `z-index: -1;` & that worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

z-index on ie7 stacks the elements on the same level so you would need to apply the z-indexes to the `.container` divs to make it work properly